# Uniform convergence for $ x \in [2, +\infty) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could you give me a hint on how to prove that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1+nx)}{nx^n} $$ converges uniformly for $ x\in[2,+\infty) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Weierstrass test

$$\left|\frac{\log(1+nx)}{nx^n}\right| \leqslant \frac{nx}{nx^n}= (x^{-1})^{n-1} \leqslant \, \ldots$$

Comment: Oh thank you very much. It was straightforward but I couldn't see that.

Comment: @Greg: You're welcome.